# How to convert procedure without string concatenation using sql server?

Tags: sql

Can u please help me in this, I'm trying to get execute SQL statement as one statement without using string concatenation. Code is below. Then i try to do this there is an error near AND

Thanks in advance,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAdminData] 

(
    @FirstName varchar(50)= null,
    @LastName varchar(50)= null,
    @Email varchar(50)= null,
    @StartDate datetime = null,
    @EndDate datetime= null,
    @RbValue bit = 0,
    @ShareholderStatus int = 0,
    @EmailStatus int = 0,
    @State nvarchar(10) = 0,
    @debug bit = 0
)
 AS
 DECLARE @sql        nvarchar(MAX),                                
        @paramlist  nvarchar(4000)  

  IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL  OR @LastName IS NOT NULL OR @Email IS NOT NULL OR  (@StartDate IS NOT NULL And  @EndDate IS NOT NULL)
  OR @ShareholderStatus >= 0 OR @EmailStatus >= 0 OR @State IS NOT NULL

 SELECT @sql = 'select TOP 1000 id, firstname, lastname, email, state, country, status,Emaildate1,  
 case when shareexchangestatus = 0 Then ''None''
  when shareexchangestatus = 1 Then ''Saved'' 
  when shareexchangestatus = 2 Then ''Submitted''
  when shareexchangestatus = 3 Then ''Pending''
  when shareexchangestatus = 4 Then ''ReSubmitted''
  when shareexchangestatus = 5 Then ''Accepted''
  when shareexchangestatus = 6 Then ''Paid''
  when shareexchangestatus = 7 Then ''Transfered''


 Else '''' END As shareexchangestatus,lastlogindate FROM dbo.zookeepers_ShareholderExchange z with (nolock) where 1=1 '


    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND (@FirstName IS NULL OR z.firstname LIKE @FirstName + ''%'') '       
    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND (@LastName IS NULL OR z.lastname LIKE @LastName + ''%'') '     
    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND (@Email IS NULL OR z.email = @Email) '

   IF @StartDate IS NOT NULL AND  @EndDate IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            if @RbValue = 1
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND z.Emaildate1 BETWEEN convert(char(23), @StartDate, 126)  AND convert(char(23), @EndDate, 126)'   
                END
            else
                BEGIN
                     SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND z.lastlogindate BETWEEN convert(char(23), @StartDate, 126)  AND convert(char(23), @EndDate, 126)'   
                END
        END 


   IF @ShareholderStatus > 0                                           
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND z.shareexchangestatus = @ShareholderStatus ' 
   SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND (@EmailStatus IS NULL OR z.emailstatus = @EmailStatus) '
   SELECT @sql = @sql + 'AND (@State IS NULL OR z.state = @State)'

   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY z.lastlogindate'                        
   IF @debug = 1                                                    
   PRINT @sql  

   SELECT @paramlist = '@FirstName nvarchar(50),                             
                     @LastName nvarchar(50),                         
                     @Email nvarchar(100),                        
                     @StartDate datetime,                        
                     @EndDate datetime,
                      @RbValue bit,
                      @ShareholderStatus int,
                      @EmailStatus int,
                      @State nvarchar(10)'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,                               
                   @FirstName , @LastName, @Email, @StartDate,        
                   @EndDate, @RbValue,@ShareholderStatus,@EmailStatus,
                   @State
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "with recompile" it will recompile the script every time it is executed, but it seems necessary since the query takes different parameters each run.

Try this:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAdminData] 
(
    @FirstName varchar(50)= null,
    @LastName varchar(50)= null,
    @Email varchar(50)= null,
    @StartDate datetime = null,
    @EndDate datetime= null,
    @RbValue bit = 0,
    @ShareholderStatus int = 0,
    @EmailStatus int = 0,
    @State nvarchar(10) = 0,
    @debug bit = 0
) with recompile
 AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sql        nvarchar(MAX),                                
        @paramlist  nvarchar(4000)  

IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL  OR @LastName IS NOT NULL OR @Email IS NOT NULL OR  (@StartDate IS NOT NULL And  @EndDate IS NOT NULL)
OR @ShareholderStatus >= 0 OR @EmailStatus >= 0 OR @State IS NOT NULL


select TOP 1000 id, firstname, lastname, email, state, country, status,Emaildate1,  
 case shareexchangestatus 
  when 0 Then 'None'
  when 1 Then 'Saved' 
  when 2 Then 'Submitted'
  when 3 Then 'Pending'
  when 4 Then 'ReSubmitted'
  when 5 Then 'Accepted'
  when 6 Then 'Paid'
  when 7 Then 'Transfered'
 Else '' END As shareexchangestatus,
 lastlogindate 
 FROM dbo.zookeepers_ShareholderExchange z with (nolock) 
 where (@FirstName IS NULL OR z.firstname LIKE @FirstName + '%')
 AND (@LastName IS NULL OR z.lastname LIKE @LastName + '%') 
 AND (@Email IS NULL OR z.email = @Email) 
 AND (@EmailStatus IS NULL OR z.emailstatus = @EmailStatus) 
 AND (@State IS NULL OR z.state = @State) 
 ORDER BY z.lastlogindate

END
```